# How to set up Shibboleth in a multi-tenanted subdirectory-based system requiring multiple idPs

Tags: iis, coldfusion, saml, multi-tenant, shibboleth

I'm a Shibboleth/SAML newbie and I have the following configuration:

1. Single IIS website/URL (`www.sample.com`)
2. Multiple subdirectories, each representing a standalone Coldfusion application (`www.sample.com/tenant1`, `www.sample.com/tenant2`)
3. Our server has HSTS enabled (require HTTPS connections)
4. We have a single SSL certificate for our URL.

I need the ability for each of the applications to have their own idP in Shibboleth.

It appears that one possible route would be to create unique websites in IIS that map to subdomains (tenant1.sample.com, tenant2.sample.com).  However, that would require some changes to our certificate and would appear to be a maintenance issue with changes having to occur on multiple technological levels every time we add a tenant.

So, before I start chasing the most complicated solution, I was hoping that somebody with more experience (any experience, really) could analyze my current architecture and needs and offer a better solution (or simply confirm the subdomain solution as being the best option).